# AppSettings not appearing in ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I'm porting a project from .NET Framework to .NET Core, and everything was largely successful. The only struggle is the `appSettings` within the `App.config`—they're not showing up! The code is below:

**App.config**

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="msg" value="I am here"/>
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Connection String" connectionString="dataHere" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I try to reference it like this

```
// This shows up!
string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection String"].ConnectionString;

// But when I try to reference the appSettings, they don't...
string message = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["msg"];
```

I've tried reinstalling packages, rebuilding, swearing—the whole gamut. I've looked at every thread pertaining to the issue (as far as I know), but feel free to redirect me if you think you've found something pertinent. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you tried to switch from XML to JSON configuration files? Maybe this is the solution to your problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration

Comment: I think that's what I'm going to do... I was just being stubborn and wanted to leave as much of the original code as possible. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Cheers! I totally get you, I've been there, too ;)

Comment: This post [here](https://rimdev.io/what-works-and-what-doesnt-with-configurationmanager-appsettings-using-aspnetcore31/) was the one that helped me to keep using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager with App.config https://rimdev.io/what-works-and-what-doesnt-with-configurationmanager-appsettings-using-aspnetcore31/